# Is there a way to trigger a mat-dialog component with #mdDialog Service?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material

I'm using a hybrid AngularJS/Angular application and my use case is I want to click a button, which is in my AngularJS code, that will trigger a mat-dialog component that I've written (which also works with other Angular components). My question is how can i get this mat-dialog component to trigger from AngularJS.

I've tried playing around using `$mdDialog.show({})` with various properties such as trying to point it to the template of the mat-dialog component and trying to pass in my scope variables that the Angular component needs access to  but with no such luck

Comment: Forget to mention, but I have downgraded the Angular component in my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I can solve this problem by adding another `@Input()` to another Angular component that is already using my `mat-dialog` component. Then make sure that this angular component is implementing `onChanges` to watch for changes to the input variable. When changes are detected then I can trigger a method to kick off the `mat-dialog`.

Comment: Hi @werty0u, can you share some code snippet, how you have done this ?